# can you limit the number of items per column of a QMenu?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, pyside2

I'm working on a gui using pyside2 (essentially pyqt5).  In it, I've created a right click popup menu using `QtCore.Qt.CustomContextMenu` and a `QMenu`.

The number of actions added to the QMenu (via the 'addAction' method) is dynamic.  When enough are added, a second column gets created in the popup menu, but that first column will take up the whole vertical height of my screen.

I can't seem to figure out how to adjust it so that each column can only have, say, 20 items in it before another column is added.  Or is there a way to tell the QMenu to make x amount of columns?

Am I missing something incredibly obvious...?

Comment: QMenu layout is quite complex, and in my experience I've never found a reliable way to achieve what you ask, since the geometry is completely computed privately. Have you considered grouping actions in sub menus?

Comment: yeah... I guess I can do that - was kind of hoping there was a way to just tell it how many actions per column, or how many columns to make and it would divided it up for me...

Comment: Well, it's not *impossible*. It's just really difficult, and unless you can test it with lots of OS and configurations, there's always the possibility of unexpected behavior: the problem is that the layout is completely internal, and you can only "fake" it by simulating a menu that will override many functions (including painting and keyboard navigation): see this [partially related answer](//stackoverflow.com/a/65987818) that shows the complexity of a similar approach. A possible work around would be a [QWidgetAction](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidgetaction.html) that could contain *all* the actions.

Comment: bleh - well, thanks for the info... sub menus looks like the way I'll be going...